# Unexpected IOCTL sent to my uclinux (ARM) driver(s)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, ioctl

Having written my character drivers to use .unlocked_ioctl and a user-space app to test them I am getting an unexpected call to the ioctl function when the devices are opened from user-space.

The driver and app both use the same header file where I define "my" identifying character to be '8'.  A dev-err output message from the driver shows that the unexpected ioctl identifying character is 'T' (see below).

When running the test app, which opens both drivers but only targets one based on the command line arguments, the unexpected ioctl call shows up for each driver.

I wondered about a 'debug' kernel configuration for ioctl but could not find any setting like that.

The header file has the following:

```
#define RLY_IOCTL_BASE  '8'
#define IOC_RLY_GETLAST _IOR(RLY_IOCTL_BASE, 0, u8)
#define IOC_RLY_SETRELAYS _IOW(RLY_IOCTL_BASE, 1, u8)
```

The driver source has this in their respective ioctl callback functions:

```
if (_IOC_TYPE(cmd) != RLY_IOCTL_BASE) {
    dev_err(&RLYspi->dev,
        "IOCTL: cmd is not for us! (Ty=%c, num=%d, size=%d, dir=%d)\n",
            _IOC_TYPE(cmd), _IOC_NR(cmd), _IOC_SIZE(cmd), _IOC_DIR(cmd));
    return -EINVAL;
}
dev_info(&RLYspi->dev, "IOCTL: cmd num-%d, size=%d, dir=%x\n",
                            _IOC_NR(cmd), _IOC_SIZE(cmd), _IOC_DIR(cmd));

switch (cmd)
```

And the user-space test application has this for opening the /dev/x drivers to get file handles and descriptors:

```
afe_fp = fopen(AFE_DEVICE_NAME, "r");
if (NULL == afe_fp) {
    printf ("Could not open device %s!\n", AFE_DEVICE_NAME);
    return 1;
}

afe_fd = fileno (afe_fp);       /* Gets the file descriptor from fp */

/* Open dev/ame_sq_rly */
rly_fp = fopen(RLY_DEVICE_NAME, "r");
if (NULL == rly_fp) {
    printf ("Could not open device %s!\n", RLY_DEVICE_NAME);
    return 1;
}

rly_fd = fileno (rly_fp);       /* Gets the file descriptor from fp */
```

The calls are like this from the test application based on the command line arguments (one command shown):

```
if (IOBase == 8) {
    /* driverapp r b (read_command) */
    else if ((argc == 3) && ((argv[1][0] == 'r') || (argv[1][0] == 'R'))){
        ret = ioctl(rly_fd, IOC_RLY_GETLAST, &RlyVal);
        if (ret < 0) {
            perror("ioctl('IOC_RLY_GETLAST')");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf ("Relay shifter last value: 0x%02X\n", RlyVal);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I expect to just get the output from the accepted command from the driver (dev_info) and then the output from the printf in the test application.

When the driverapp (test application) is run I get the following console output:

```
# driverapp r 8
<device A info>: IOCTL: cmd is not for us! (Ty=T, num=1, size=0, dir=0)
<device B info>: IOCTL: cmd is not for us! (Ty=T, num=1, size=0, dir=0)
<device B info>: IOCTL: cmd num-0, size=1, dir=2
Relay shifter last value: 0x00
#
```

Both drivers (shown as 'device A' and 'device B' above) are called with the unexpected ioctl call on device open.  I tested this by just opening one of the devices instead of both and I only get one unexpected ioctl call for the driver that was opened.

Where are the two unexpected 'T' ioctl commands coming from?

Many thanks for any information.

Comment: You can report calling pid. May be somebody called your driver from another process. You can see that `dir=0` is `_IOC_NONE`. But you declare only read or write IOs.

Comment: That looks like the `TCGETS` ioctl command code 0x5401 (this is the older style of command codes with no size or direction information, just a type and a command number). My guess is that the standard library is calling `isatty(fd)` on the file descriptor.

Comment: @VladimirPustovalov, I am printing the pid value obtained using 'current->pid' and it is the same for the unknown ioctl as for the accepted one.  I still do not understand what is calling the ioctl with a type 'T'.

Comment: @IanAbbott, `isatty` did not show up in my search of the kernel sources (4.5).  Is this some standard practice when any driver file is opened...even when not associated with anything (other than being a character driver)?

Comment: @BillE `isatty` is a user-space POSIX C library function, so you won't find it in the kernel sources. On Linux, at least with glibc, `isatty` calls `tcgetattr`, which in turn calls `ioctl` using the `TCGETS` command.

Comment: @BillE The `TCGETS` ioctl is definitely used on the standard input and output file descriptors because it uses this information to decide what sort of stdio stream buffering to use. I think it is also used on the file descriptors of other stdio streams created by `fopen` for the same reason.

Comment: @BillE, Actually, glibc seems to do `fstat` first, and only does the `isatty` check for character special files.

Comment: @IanA, so what I am understanding is that any char device driver that implements ioctl will have this call made to it when a user-space program opens the driver.  So this particular unknown ioctl call could be filtered so only "really" unknown ones are shown.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: @IanA (and any others), is there a different way to register the driver (but still a char device) that would tell glibc that this driver can be ignored?  The device is currently created with: `pDev = device_create(pClass, NULL, devNo, NULL, DEVICE_NAME)`.

Comment: @BillE Not really. Your driver code should just return an `-ENOTTY` error for unknown ioctl command codes. This is the "Inappropriate ioctl for device" error code (or historically, the "[Not a typewriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_a_typewriter)" error code, which explains the macro name!). You can avoid it in your own program by opening the device with `open` instead of `fopen`.

Comment: @IanA, many thanks for your interaction on this question.  For debugging purposes I was showing the unexpected ioctl (as in the original post) so I am now filtering that particular one (T) out.  The driver does return `-ENOTTY` for that and any other unhandled command.  The purpose of the driver currently requires the `fopen` for reading of data that the driver is collecting.  I can work with the unexpected ioctl now that it has become "expected".